# Launching a webpage from service crashes app

Tags: android

Trying to open a webpage whenever the device gets connected to the Internet. However the Service I use is crashing the app.
Here is the source code of the Service class:

```
public class Opener extends Service {


final byte flag=0;
byte logger=0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    while(flag==0){

        ConnectivityManager cm = 
(ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && 
activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if(isConnected)
        {
            if(logger==10)
            {
                this.stopSelf();
            }
            ++logger;

            Intent blower = new Intent();
            blower.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            blower.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);

blower.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.developer.android.com"));
            startActivity(blower);
        }
        else{
            ;
        }

        }

}





@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Here is the Logcat as well :

```
>  Process: antivirus.dc.lab.antivirus, PID: 2264
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service antivirus.dc.lab.antivirus.Opener@21f96590 with Intent { cmp=antivirus.dc.lab.antivirus/.Opener }: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2881)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
            at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1232)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1219)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:322)
            at antivirus.dc.lab.antivirus.Opener.onStart(Opener.java:51)
            at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:458)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2864)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

From a similar question, Found an answer to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` however does not work in my case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've named your Intent `blower`, but you are passing `intent` to `startActivity`. It should be

```
startActivity(blower);
```

Comment: oops, fixed that . It still crashes

Comment: Did you try adding `blower.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` ?

Comment: if you got the answer then please accept it as answer.